# PHP Jquery Ajax Post data not saving to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm studying jquery ajax php post, I'm getting the success message but the data is not saving on my database, the page is online please see it on the link below.

http://marlz13.net78.net/Feedback%20AJAX/

Here is my Send JS script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('form #response').hide();

 $('#submit').click(function(e) {

// prevent forms default action until
// error check has been performed
e.preventDefault();

// grab form field values
var valid = '';
var required = ' is required.';
var name = $('form #name').val();
var email = $('form #email').val();
var message = $('form #message').val();
var honeypot = $('form #honeypot').val();
var humancheck = $('form #humancheck').val();

// perform error checking
if (name = '' || name.length <= 2) {
    valid = '<p>Your name' + required +'</p>';  
}

if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
    valid += '<p>Your email' + required +'</p>';                                                  
}

if (message = '' || message.length <= 5) {
    valid += '<p>A message' + required + '</p>';    
}

if (honeypot != 'http://') {
    valid += '<p>Spambots are not allowed.</p>';    
}

if (humancheck != '') {
    valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>'; 
}

// let the user know if there are erros with the form
if (valid != '') {

    $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
        .html('<strong>Please correct the errors below.</strong>' +valid).fadeIn('fast');           
}
// let the user know something is happening behind the scenes
// serialize the form data and send to our ajax function
else {

$('form#response').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('Processing...').fadeIn('fast');                                       

    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    submitForm(formData);       
 }          

 });
 });

// make our ajax request to the server
function submitForm(formData) {

$.ajax({    
type: 'POST',
url: 'feedback.php',        
data: formData,
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
timeout: 7000,
success: function(data) {           

    $('form #response').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast'); 

    if ($('form #response').hasClass('success')) {

        setTimeout("$('form #response').fadeOut('fast')", 5000);
    }

 },
 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .html('<p>There was an<strong> ' + errorThrown +
                      '</strong> error due to a<strong> ' + textStatus +
                      '</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');           
 },             
 complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {           

    $('form')[0].reset();
 }
 });    
 };
```

Here's the PHP script

```
  <?php 
  // Establishing connection with server..
  $connection = mysql_connect("databaseserver", "username", "password");

 // Selecting Database 
 $db = mysql_select_db("db", $connection);

 sleep(2);
 //Sanitize incoming data and store in variable
 $name = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])));          
 $email = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])));
 $message = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'])));        
 $humancheck = $_POST['humancheck'];
 $honeypot = $_POST['honeypot'];

 if ($honeypot == 'http://' && empty($humancheck)) {    

    //Validate data and return success or error message
    $error_message = '';    
    $reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,4}$/";

    if (!preg_match($reg_exp, $email)) {

                $error_message .= "<p>A valid email address is required.</p>";             
    }
    if (empty($name)) {

                $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your name.</p>";              
    }           
    if (empty($message)) {

                $error_message .= "<p>A message is required.</p>";
    }       
    if (!empty($error_message)) {
                $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = "<h3>Oops! The request was successful but your form is not filled out correctly.</h3>".$error_message;                 
                echo json_encode($return);
                exit();
    } else {

            //Insert query 
 mysql_query("INSERT into formdata (name, email, desc) values ('$name', '$email', '$message')");

        //connection closed
        mysql_close($connection);   

        $return['error'] = false;
        $return['msg'] = "<p>Thanks for your feedback " .$name .".</p>"; 

        echo json_encode($return);



      }     
 } else {

 $return['error'] = true;
 $return['msg'] = "<h3>Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please try again.</h3>"; 
 echo json_encode($return);
 }

 ?>
```

This is on the head of my HTM

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>AJAX form tutorial using jQuery and PHP</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax_submit.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Are you checking your message in console ??

Comment: Your success message doesn't seem to be dependent on the success of your sql statement executing. You may be getting some sort of error, have you checked if there is an sql error happening?

Comment: HI Ideal, I dont see any message on the console..I made page online please see it on link below. http://marlz13.net78.net/Feedback%20AJAX/

Comment: Hi Rasclatt, I don't see any SQL error.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_connect` use [mysqli](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

Comment: Hi sorry about that but I'm just a beginner, I will explore those soon when I'm fully experienced with mysql...

Comment: you can try to put the response of mysql_query() into a variable like $save = mysql_query('... '); - that should be true if the query is a success, so you can say if(!$save) { $return["mysql_err"] = mysql_error(); } - by the way, "desc" is a reserved word, so you might wanna write it with backticks (`) in your query.

Comment: Wow thank you so much!!! That fix it I inserted the code below after sql close and change the name of table field desc to description.   if(!$save) { 
   $return["mysql_err"] = mysql_error(); 
   
   }

Comment: Great - I'll write it as an answer then;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i said in the comment, DESC is a reserved word in mysql, so you should put backticks arround it like below.

Also you can check what the error is with mysql_error().

```
$save = mysql_query("INSERT into formdata (name, email, `desc`) values ('$name', '$email', '$message')");
if(!$save) { 
    $return["mysql_err"] = mysql_error(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it

```
       <?php 
      // Establishing connection with server..
      $connection = mysql_connect("databaseserver", "username", "password");

     // Selecting Database 
     $db = mysql_select_db("db", $connection);

     sleep(2);
     //Sanitize incoming data and store in variable
     $name = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name1'])));         
     $email = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email1'])));
     $message = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message1'])));       
     //$humancheck = $_POST['humancheck'];
     //$honeypot = $_POST['honeypot'];

     //if ($honeypot == 'http://' && empty($humancheck)) 
     //{    

        //Validate data and return success or error message
        $error_message = '';    
        $reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,4}$/";

        if (!preg_match($reg_exp, $email)) {

                    $error_message .= "<p>A valid email address is required.</p>";             
        }
        if (empty($name)) {

                    $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your name.</p>";              
        }           
        if (empty($message)) {

                    $error_message .= "<p>A message is required.</p>";
        }       
        if(empty($error_message)==true)
       {
                    $return['error'] = true;
        $return['msg'] = "<h3>Oops! The request was successful but your form is not filled out correctly.</h3>".$error_message;                 
                    echo json_encode($return);
                    exit();
        } else {    

                //Insert query 
     mysql_query("insert into formdata (name, email, desc) values ('$name', '$email', '$message')");

            //connection closed
            mysql_close($connection);   

            $return['error'] = false;
            $return['msg'] = "<p>Thanks for your feedback " .$name .".</p>"; 

            echo json_encode($return);



          }     


     ?>
```